# No keyboard is recognized at POST

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bios

My motherboard is ASUS PRIME Z270-AR.

I have a USB keyboard that works fine in the OS. I've also tried a PS/2 keyboard without luck.  I was able to reach the BIOS last summer.  I think I've updated firmware since I last accessed the BIOS, so maybe the new version is broken?

Here's a list of things that have been attempted:

- made sure Fast Startup is turned off
- 2 different USB keyboards
- switched current keyboard's polling switch to BIOS
- USB to PS/2 connector on a USB keyboard
- an old PS/2 keyboard
- disconnected the CPU fan from the motherboard (attempting to force BIOS)
- removed CMOS battery
- tried advanced startup, but no UEFI option was available

Comment: Did you try the windows Boot to UEFI commands?  https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5831-boot-uefi-firmware-settings-inside-windows-10-a.html   You can also try to use EZ Update in Windows to flash your bios, given the keyboard works in that environment. This can be found in the Asus AI suite. https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/utils/ASUS_AISuite3_Win7-81-10_V10161_HM.zip  Try updating to 1301. It should reset your settings.

Comment: @NatsuKage Thanks for the EZ update information.  I didn't know about it and will definitely use it.  I'd still like to figure out what is going on here that prevents the keyboard from working, purely out of curiosity.  As for the boot to UEFI, that's what I was referring to with the advanced startup.  I don't have an UEFI option during boot for some reason.

Comment: Before all else: did you try removing all bootable devices (HDD/SSD/USB, etc)? Often it might just ask you if you want to go to BIOS if there's no bootable drive, and most UEFI just go straight to it when there's nothing to boot with.

Comment: I haven't tried that, but the end goal is to be able to access it or change values easily like you're supposed to with a key press on POST.  Hopefully the EZ Update will work for me.  I have 5 drives so that will be the last resort.

Comment: Updating to a new BIOS with EZ Update worked.  I have access to the keyboard now.  I'm not sure why it stopped working at some point, but hopefully this will fix it in the future if it happens again.

Comment: Alright! Good to hear. You can post your steps as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific motherboard, the solution was updating the BIOS.  At some point, something changed that prevented the keyboard from working.  I never found out why or if it could be fixed, but updating the BIOS got rid of the problem.